# Creating a shell script that takes a string input from a user, asks for a file name and reports whether the string is present in the file?

Tags: string, file, input

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
if [ -f $FILE ];
then
   echo "File $FILE exists"
else
   echo "File $FILE does not exists"
fi
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct for what I'm doing.

Comment: did you tried this and what was output if your tried this?

Comment: "asks for a filename" is missing, as well as the reporting of a match

Comment: I tried this and it's not doing what I want it to, I need it to search for a specific file, then give you the option to search for a specific word within this specific file. Is this posible?